# How to connect spotify player without website

Tags: javascript, html, windows, spotify

So what I'm trying to do is set up an app that is able to play and skip songs on spotify from my computer. The problem is that the spotify api is for web-based apps and uses html to show examples of how to connect to the spotify player:

```
<script src="https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js"></script>
```

I was wondering if anyone would have any idea of how to connect like this in a normal javascript file rather than through html.

Comment: Do you need to include that script? Can't you just use their [HTTP API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/)?

Comment: I am but that's how it says I need to connect to the player. The other api is just for retrieving data and stuff.

Comment: Well, even if you copy & pasted the code at that URI, it probably wouldn't work because it needs access to web APIs.